# cygpath not able to convert Windows path to Linux path

Tags: cygwin, cygpath

Im trying to convert the file paths to/from Linux and Windows on Windows Machine.

unix path to windows works fine.

```
$ cygpath -w /cygdrive/c/CYGWIN/CYGBuild/build.mak
C:\CYGWIN\CYGBuild\build.mak
```

But windows path to Linux gives wrong output. i.e Missing '/' and also cygdrive

```
$ cygpath -u c:\cygwin\cygbuild\build.mak
c:cygwincygbuildbuild.mak
```

Anyone faced this issue?? Share your experience.

Thanks

Comment: Note this is not Linux (nor is WFL). They are Gnu. Cygwin uses a dll named `cygwin.dll` do do the job that a Unix kernel (such as Linux) would do. (Gnu+Linux) - Linux + dll = Gnu + dll

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I got answer for this question.

```
cygpath -u 'c:\cygwin\cygbuild\build.mak'
```

i.e path should be given in single quotation.

Answer (score 3):

Actually as far as I know; you need **forward slashes** in paths used in cygwin. Single quotations help in cases where there are spaces (and my guess in this case; using backslashes instead of forward slashes) in the path. Otherwise backslashes are like **escape characters**, while spaces (although not in your case) require escape characters themselves. So quoting the path tends to eliminate such hassles.

Here are links that help me understand this:

- [This](http://www.stanford.edu/class/ee368/Android/Tutorial-2-OpenCV-for-Android-Setup-Windows.pdf) opencv (using cygwin) tutorial, page 4, where there's an example of paths used, with and without quotes, indicating when one might need them.
- Also [this](http://cygwin.com/faq-nochunks.html#faq.using.filename-spaces) is
  very useful; a list of Cygwin's FAQs, including how to deal with
  spaces (or in this case, backslashes in the path where adding quotes would help).

Answer (score 0):

cygpath's `-m` option is probably the easiest solution. Windows software generally accepts `/` as well as `\`. (There may be a few exceptions, but the development tools I work with have all been fine with it.)

```
$ cygpath -m /cygdrive/c/CYGWIN/CYGBuild/build.mak

C:/Cygwin/CYGBuild/build.mak
```

Answer (score 0):

No one seems to have explain why, we here is an explanation.

`Cygpath` will accept slashes, and back-slashes: `c:/cygwin/cygbuild/build.mak` `c:\cygwin\cygbuild\build.mak`. However the shell will interpret the back-slashes, therefore you need to stop the shell from interpreting the back-slashes.

You can stop the shell from interpreting back-slashes, in arguments, by preceding them with a back-slash, or by quoting (with single quotes): `c:\\cygwin\\cygbuild\\build.mak` or `'c:\cygwin\cygbuild\build.mak'`.

Double quotes will not help in this case. Double quotes stops argument breaking on space, but does not stop interpretation of escapes (`\`), or dollar (`$`) expansion.