# Convert a posix path to windows in git bash (terminal or script)?

Tags: windows, git-bash

A few programs/libraries on windows demand windows only paths. So from a git bash terminal I had to do this:

```
$ export FOO="d:\\path\\to\\folder"
```

Is there an alternative to this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have seen used in the past (for instance by [Git itself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47231865/6309)) the [`cygpath` command](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/cygpath.html).

> Convert Unix and Windows format paths, or output system path information
>
> The `-u` and `-w` options indicate whether you want a conversion to UNIX (POSIX) format (`-u`) or to Windows format (`-w`).

---

[propatience](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6533028/propatience) points out in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65679634/convert-a-posix-path-to-windows-in-git-bash-terminal-or-script/65680101?noredirect=1#comment127734951_65680101) to the example "[`cygpath -u 'c:\cygwin\cygbuild\build.mak'`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12621034/6309)", using single quote.